# how to do math function (divide) for results of a group by function

Tags: sql

I have a table of 6 digit event numbers;
i am trying to count one event number (let's say 600189) that has occurred during a specific time period, and divide it by a count of a second event number (lets say 600122) during the same time period.

the below query gets my two counts but I want to modify the query to do the calculation `(count of 600189 / count of 600122) * 100` :

```
select count (messageno) 
from event
where timestamp > '2019-03-14' and timestamp < '2019-03-15' and
messageno in ('600122','600189')
group by messageno
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of query patterns.

One approach is conditional aggregation. We can return a value of 1 if a condition is true, otherwise return 0, and add up the 1s and 0s with a SUM aggregate to get a count. Consider:

For MySQL, we can do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM( IF(e.messageno='600122',1,0) )   AS cnt_600122
     , SUM( IF(e.messageno='600189',1,0) )   AS cnt_600189
     , ( 100.0
       * SUM( IF(e.messageno='600122',1,0) ) 
       / SUM( IF(e.messageno='600189',1,0) )
       ) AS pct
   FROM event e
  WHERE e.timestamp > '2019-03-14'
    AND e.timestamp < '2019-03-15'
    AND e.messageno IN ('600122','600189')
```

More portable ANSI standards compliant equivalent will work for Microsoft SQL Server et al.:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE e.messageno WHEN '600122' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  AS cnt_600122
     , SUM( CASE e.messageno WHEN '600189' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  AS cnt_600189
     , ( 100.0
       * SUM( CASE e.messageno WHEN '600122' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
       / SUM( CASE e.messageno WHEN '600122' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
       ) AS pct
   FROM event e
  WHERE e.timestamp > '2019-03-14'
    AND e.timestamp < '2019-03-15'
    AND e.messageno IN ('600122','600189')
```

Other approaches would be to do aggregation in an inline view(s), or use subqueries in the SELECT list:

```
  SELECT 100.0
       * ( SELECT SUM(1) 
             FROM event e
            WHERE e.timestamp  > '2019-03-14'
              AND e.timestamp  < '2019-03-15'
              AND e.messageno IN ('600122')
         )
       / ( SELECT SUM(1) 
             FROM event e
            WHERE e.timestamp  > '2019-03-14'
              AND e.timestamp  < '2019-03-15'
              AND e.messageno IN ('600189')
          ) 
            AS pct
```

Comment: i tried the first example and it errored out -Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Syntax provided in this answer was for MySQL, not Microsoft SQL Server. Answer edited to include more portable, more ANSI standards compliant version of the first example.

Comment: both of those worked !  thx! i will run both independently to see which one runs faster.  Much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when messageno = '600122' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_1,
       sum(case when messageno = '600189' then 1 end) as cnt_2,
       ( sum(case when messageno = '600122' then 1 else 0 end) /
         sum(case when messageno = '600189' then 1 end)
       ) as ratio            
from event
where timestamp > '2019-03-14' and
      timestamp < '2019-03-15' and
      messageno in ('600122', '600189');
```

Note that the `else` in the denominator is removed.  This is intentional.  If there are no messages with that number, then this returns `NULL` instead of a divide-by-zero error.